# Duda de bucle while

Tags: python, bucle-for, bucles, while, random

Tengo una sobre el bucle while en python
Cuando un bucle while se ejecuta si dentro hay un bucle for o condicional if
que se han ejecutado ya no se vuelven a ejecutar o si?
Ejemplo:

```
import random
intentos=0
while True:

    for i in range(2):

        o=random.randint(1,2)

        i=random.randint(1,2)
        intentos+=1
        if  o==i:

            break;
print(intentos)
print("FIN")
```

Se que el codigo no tiene sentido es un ejemplo(el de verdad tiene unas 110 lineas), es solo para mostrar que el for no se vuelve a ejecutar por lo q el if tampoco y el while se vuelve  ∞ y el editor se colasa(se q el while le podria poner condicion pero el codigo de verdad tiene un if con break y lo puse asi para que tuviera el condicional if )

Esta un poco mal redactado, es una advertencia para esa gente que se pone a corregir faltas, cosa que no me interesa!

Comment: ¿Cuál es la condición para que el while se cumpla en tu ejemplo?

Comment: @JeanGotopo es un `while True` siempre se ejecuta

Comment: Lo que pasa es que break interrumpe el ciclo for, no el while, tenés que poner un break para el while a la altura del for

Comment: lo que deduzco es que el while siempre se ejecutara, ya que el break, esta adentro del for, lo que hace que el ciclo for se detenga, pero nunca el while, además este se ejecuta cuando loas 2 variables sean iguales, pero si se ejecutara siempre el ciclo for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira vamos a analizar tu bucle.

```py
while True:
    for i in range(2):
```

En esta parte el bloque `while` se ejecutará siempre en cada iteracion del `while` se ejecutará el bucle `for`, este se ejecutara 2 veces, al terminar se volverá al inicio del bucle `while` y repite el mismo proceso, la cosa viene en la condición que pones.

```py
    ...
        if  o==i:
            break;
```

Según tu con la sentencia `break` se deberá terminar el ciclo `while` pero **NO**, las sentencias `break`, `continue` y `pass` se utilizan para los `while` y `for` (para los ciclos), y lo que pasa ahí es que se interrumpe el ciclo `for`, es decir si se cumple `o==i` en la primera iteración ya no se ejecutará la segunda iteración.
Para resolver tu problema se puede crear una variable de control que monitoree la condición. Algo así

```py
intentos=0
condicion = True
while condicion:
    for i in range(2):

        o=random.randint(1,2)
        i=random.randint(1,2)

        intentos+=1
        if  o==i:
            condicion = False; #cambiamos la variable
            break #rompemos el for para no seguir

print(intentos)
print("FIN")
```

Como dije, una vez acabado el ciclo `while` este volverá al principio por lo que volverá a evaluar la variable `condicion` y como esta es `False` el ciclo ya no se ejecutará más.

Pero ¿y si ponemos doble `break`?

```py
while True:
    for i in range(2):
        ...
        if  o==i:
            break;
    break
```

Pues esto solo ejecutará el bucle una vez, al llegar al final el `while` ejecuta el `break` por lo que parará su ejecución en la primera *vuelta* y no sirve. También podríamos hacer almo mas simple, evaluar la coincidencia `o==i`

```py
intentos=0
i,o = 0,1
while i!=o:

    for i in range(2):
        o=random.randint(1,2)

        i=random.randint(1,2)
        print(o,i, intentos)
        intentos+=1

print(intentos)
print("FIN")
```

Sin embargo esto no es del todo correcto, pues el ciclo `while` evaluara la condición al finalizar todo lo que tenga adentro, por lo que si `i==o` en la primera iteración del `for` el bucle no pará, al final el `while` evaluara el ultimo valor que tome `i`, `o` al final del `for`

Answer (score 0):

me llama la atención:

```
while True:
    for i in range(2):
        ...
        if  o==i:
            break;
    break
```

Pues esto solo ejecutará el bucle una vez, al llegar al final el while ejecuta el break por lo que parará su ejecución en la primera vuelta y no sirve.

Siendo que:

```
#-*- coding: utf -8 -*-
intentos=0
while True:
    for i in range(19):
        print(i,end="")
        if  i==18:
            break
        intentos+=1
    break
print("\n",intentos)
print("FIN")
```

produce:

```
0123456789101112131415161718
 18
FIN
```

No se ve que el ciclo no se cumpla.

Comment: El `while True`  sobraría si solo ejecutas el `for` y pues al terminar el `for` rompes el `while` que solo se ejecuto 1 vez

Comment: @Christian  como lo mostró el usuario no hay una condicional extra para el while, el segundo break iría con alguna condicional obviamente.